# Filter operation in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe **dataframe1**, I wanted to get some filtered records from this dataframe, I have successfully applied **like** and **isin** operation on it:

```
dataframe1.where((col('string_v').like("d_ms%"))).show()
dataframe1.where((col('string_v').isin("d_ms-92","d_ms_93"))).show()
```

But can some one help me how can I apply filter conditions **not isin** and **not like** using pyspark, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Either

```
dataframe1.where(~(col('string_v').like("d_ms%"))).show()
dataframe1.where(~(col('string_v').isin("d_ms-92","d_ms_93"))).show()
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import not

dataframe1.where(not(col('string_v').like("d_ms%"))).show()
dataframe1.where(not(col('string_v').isin("d_ms-92","d_ms_93"))).show()
```